# How do I use WTL::CHyperLink?

Tags: c++, mfc, atl, wtl

I am trying to use WTL::CHyperLink in order to display a clickable link on my application.

According to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4029/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-V-Advanced-Dialog-UI#chyperlink), I need to attach it to a Static Text control.

So, in my GUI, I have now created a static text control with an ID of IDC_LINK

In my DDX MAP:

```
BEGIN_DDX_MAP(MyDialog)
    DDX_CONTROL_HANDLE(IDC_LINK, m_link)
END_DDX_MAP()
```

and as a member variable:

```
CHyperLink m_link;
```

However, I am always left with this:

```
Error C2679: Binary Operator '=': No operator accepting a right-hand operant of type 'ATL::CWindow' (or no suitable conversion possible)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is that like the standard `SysLink` control?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I actually don't know, WTL is so poorly documented, I don't know much more than what I found

Comment: That article is old, maybe you just need SysLink, you can drag & drop the control in dialog resource editor or see this [**link**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also make sure the [manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32729776/4603670) is setup correctly

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I tried to replace my static text with SysLink but I still get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WTL `CHyperLink` is a custom control implementation class and unlike other classes like `CEdit`, which are thin `HWND` wrappers, you cannot initialize the control by using assignment operator with window handle (which is what `DDX_CONTROL_HANDLE` map tries to do) and by just manipulating window handle only in general. You are supposed to either create a control window from scratch (`CHyperLink::Create`), or take a pre-created static control and subclass it using `CHyperLink::SubclassWindow`.

With static control already existing in the dialog template, which is supposed to back your hyperlink, you can try `DDX_CONTROL` macro instead of `DDX_CONTROL_HANDLE` because it attempts to initialize by subclassing using `SubclassWindow` call.

Non-DDX initialization code snippet is [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.wtl/16104): `SubclassWindow` + `SetHyperLink` calls in `WM_INITDIALOG` handler.

You asked a similar question before: [Error when trying to hook up a control with DDX_CONTROL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528471/error-when-trying-to-hook-up-a-control-with-ddx-control) And at that time you confused the same two DDX macros the other way...

Comment: Thanks, using DDX_CONTROL worked perfectly. I only recently started to do GUIs with WTL and it's somewhat hard to keep track of all I came across and learned so far.